# Maximum sound duration on Android Notification

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications

What is the actual maximum duration in seconds for a custom sound played when a notification arrives in Android?

In iOS the limit is officially at [30 s](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SupportingNotificationsinYourApp.html) for custom sounds.

Comment: Ever get an answer on this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Nice to meet you here, Beat! I'm not sure that you still need the answer, but anyways:

I wasn't able to find any limit in Android documentation and decided to make a test. So I set [Beethoven's 5th Symphony (36:20)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fOk8Tm815lE&t=11s) as a notification sound and started a notification. It played the full time. So I assume, that Android has no notification sound limit.

Comment: Epic test, I've appreciated the youtube link!

Answer (score 1):

I did some tests on Android Smartphones and Tablets:

- Android 12 (Realme 8): approx 5 seconds, then it gets cut off
- Android 12 (Samsung Galaxy Tab A7 SM-T505):  Custom sound not possible - only preinstalled sounds
- Android 11 (Samsung Galaxy Tab A SM-T295): Custom sound not possible - only preinstalled sounds

To me it seems to be very much dependent on the producer how the notifications get handled.
On some older android phones I also didn't find the possibility to set individual sounds per app.

### If you are a developer

We added a process in our app that gets called by the notification to play a sound for an alarm - this way it's a little bit more consistent.
Right now the process gets killed after a max of 30 seconds - so thats the maximum playtime in this scenario.
We also required a longer notification sound in iOs but we didn't find a possibility yet.

It's a pain in the arm just to trigger a simple but important alarm in 2022...